# Advanced Batch-File: Dynamically setting a variable with set /p and redirection

Tags: batch-file, redirect

Hey there.
Basically, I have a batch-file, that goes through all model and texture files, saves their absolut path and then passes the gathered pathes to my converter.exe. 
Currently I do this by appending the path of each input file to a `set /p` variable, with the output of that variable redirected into a params.txt.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%MODEL_SRC%" /a:d-h /b') do (
 set /p=-o="%MODEL_DST%\%%a.res" >cvtr_params.txt<nul
 for /f %%b in ('dir "%MODEL_SRC%\%%a\*.obj" /a:-d-h /b') do (
  <nul (set/p=""%MODEL_SRC%\%%a\%%b" ") >>cvtr_params.txt
 )
 for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('dir "%TEX_SRC%\%%a\*.png" /a:-d-h /b') do (
  <nul (set/p=""%TEX_SRC%\%%a\%%c" ") >>cvtr_params.txt
 )
 start /b /wait "" bin\converter.exe @cvtr_params.txt >nul
)
del cvtr_params.txt
```

The params.txt would look like this:
`-o="ConvertedPath\Ingame.res" "ModelPath\Model1.obj" "ModelPath\Model2.obj" "TexPath\Tex1.png" "TexPath\Tex2.png"`
And so on and so forth.
And yes, the code HAS to be this complicated for actually appending to the end of the line, not a new line.

Now I thought, that the cvtr_params.txt is unnecessary, and had this approach, which did nearly the same, just not redirecting the "question" of the `set /p` variable into a params.txt but actually just assigning `set /p params` to the "question" of `set /p z`.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%MODEL_SRC%" /a:d-h /b') do (
 set /p params=<nul
 set /p z=-o="%MODEL_DST%\%%a.res" <nul
 for /f %%b in ('dir "%MODEL_SRC%\%%a\*.obj" /a:-d-h /b') do (
  <nul (set/p=""%MODEL_SRC%\%%a\%%b" ")
 )
 for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('dir "%TEX_SRC%\%%a\*.png" /a:-d-h /b') do (
  <nul (set/p=""%TEX_SRC%\%%a\%%c" ")
 )
 start /b /wait "" bin\converter.exe !params!
)
endlocal
```

But somehow, the `!params!` variable appears as empty. (an echo delivers `"ECHO is set to <OFF>`") 
Now I'm at the end of my wits, and I just started seriously working with batch files like 3 days ago, so if anyone has a good idea, let me hear it! :)

Greetz

Comment: "set /p params=xyz<nul" prints the text "xyz" without CR/LF to stdout, the use of redirecting from <nul is only for direct print without waiting for user input. The user input is here nothing, so param will not changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `params` is set to be empty at the beginning and never changed afterwards, so what do you expect?

If you want to concat elements in `params`, you should try something along the lines of

```
set params=!params! ""%TEX_SRC%\%%a\%%c" "
```

but beware, environment variables have a [maximum length of 8191 characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) since WinXP or later (less on earlier systems).

Comment: Actually, that's not quite true.
set /p params=<nul
Reads the value from any device following, which should be
set /p z=.... Anyways, I'll try the other approach, thanks!

Comment: So ofc, the approach works. Wonder why I didn't think about that.. maybe because actually thought like that, but it doesn't work with %params%, and I just recently found the EnableDelaysedExpansion. So I kinda forgot until now... anyways, +1 and accepted. Thanks again.